# Reload rails initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In application.rb, I have

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib
```

So when I modify a class under lib, my code is reloaded.

However, when I tried adding config/initializers to autoload, I noticed my code doesn't get updated.

If I'm writing an extension for the string class, I have to restart rails every time I modify my code.

Please advise?

Comment: There's also this pernicious problem that when a class is reloaded in development mode, all class attributes that where set up in initializers are lost. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49948221/326840

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initializers are only loaded when starting rails (and never reloaded). When tinkering in `config/initializers` you will have to restart rails every time.

Of course, you could make sure your code is defined in `/lib` so you can still make sure it works, by using your test-suite.

E.g. in `lib/speaker.rb` write

```
module Speaker
  def speak
    puts "Ahum, listen: #{self.to_s}"
  end
end
```

and in your initializer you could then do something like

```
class String
  include Speaker
end
```

While this will still only get loaded when starting rails, you can develop and test your module more easily.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Initializer files are loaded only once when the rails server is started. Restart the server when initialzers values are changed. 
For further information see the rails [initialization guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/initialization.html).

**Auto Reloading 'lib' on change**

You can auto reload lib files. Follow Link [Autoload and Reload lib directory on change](https://web.archive.org/web/20130830141432/http://hemju.com:80/index.php/2010/09/rails-3-quicktip-autoload-lib-directory-including-all-subdirectories/)

In Configuring Rails Applications: `config.reload_classes_only_on_change` enables or disables reloading of classes only when tracked files change. By default tracks everything on autoload paths and is set to true. If `config.cache_classes` is true, this option is ignored.

Comment: This is what my question was about; I did not want to restart the server. I wanted a better way to debug my code.