# How to set class level variables in Rails initializer when using spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-spring

In my config/initializers/transaction_logger.rb I have the following code

```
# config/initializers/transaction_logger.rb
Transaction::Logger.logger = Transaction::Logger.new("log/transations.log")
```

Every time I change the code and run the tests I get:

```
 Failure/Error: delegate :info, :warn, :debug, :error, to: :logger

 Module::DelegationError:
   #<Class:Transaction::Logger>#error delegated to logger.error, but logger is nil: Transaction::Logger
```

I have to run `spring stop` and then re-run the test again (seems initializer's code to be executing after `spring stop`)

How should I set `Transaction::Logger.logger` to avoid this problem? Thanks

Comment: Personally, I remove Spring from all my projects precisely due to this sort of problem.

Comment: @jvillian this is not acceptable for me because I spring significantly increases my tests boot time in the development

Comment: Fair enough. I'll look forward to others' answers!

Comment: @jvillian I've just found solution to my problem myself

Comment: Great sleuthing!

Comment: This question (and answer) deserve many more upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As spring documentation [says](https://github.com/rails/spring#class-reloading)

> So to avoid this problem, don't save off references to application
>   constants in your initialization code.

Seems this can be related to setting up class variables too

I've moved setting up `Transaction::Logger.logger` into `Transaction::Logger` file

```
# app/core/transaction/logger.rb
class Transaction::Logger < Logger
...
end

Transaction::Logger.logger = Transaction::Logger.new("log/transactions.log")
```